# Photo fade only in shot

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how http://www.i-donline.com/straight-ups this effect is created. The images are opacity 0 until they are loaded onto the screen then they fade up.. I imagine a jquery type of function but I have no clue how to achieve this. Are there any tutorials online? 
Thanks for all the help 
Tara

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be using the `fadeTo()` method within the `hover()` method on each image

```
$("img").hover(
    function(){ $(this).fadeTo(0.5, "slow"}, 
    function(){ $(this).fadeTo(1.0, "fast"}
);
```

Find out more about the `fadeTo()` method here: http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/